# Converting series of Arduino switches to binary series

Tags: arduino

I am currently working on a project in which there are five switches, and depending on which are on I would like it to do a specific task. I would like to know how to make it that if, say, I had switch 1 on (1), switch 2: 0, switch 3: 0: switch 4: 0, and switch 5: 1, then it would make a variable equal to 10001.

Thanks to anyone who answers!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do (disclaimer: I didn't try to compile it, but you get the idea):

```c
    #define SW_COUNT 5

    uint8_t pins[SW_COUNT] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    void setup(void) {
      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SW_COUNT; i++)
        pinMode(pins[i], INPUT);
    }

    void loop(void) {
      uint8_t combined = 0;

      for (uint8_t i = 0; i < SW_COUNT; i++) {
        combined = combined << 1;
        combined |= digitalRead(pins[i]);
      }

      // Now "combined" contains the bitmask you want
    }
```

Comment: This can be further optimized in several ways, but it's probably not worth, unless you are doing something really tight in terms of resources.
You might want to turn the for loops into functions ... but it's mostly increasing readability and slightly reducing performance, unless the compiler is smart enough to inline them.

Comment: Also, it's probably a good idea to mention that I won't be using a regular switch, I'll be using something more like this: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=72276.0

Comment: Like it says in the link, avoid pins 0, 1 and 13: they are serial TX/RX and the LED.

Comment: Ok, so I'll just change the beginning to `uint_8 pins [SW_COUNT] = {2,3,4,5,6};`

Comment: “pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);”: you mean `INPUT`. But it’s actually not needed, all pins are input by default.

Comment: Yes, INPUT, fixed that, thanks.
The idea of setting stuff explicitly is to avoid assumptions.
Even the mistake I made was easier to spot than a wrong assumption I could have made.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something more or less compatible with an Arduino Uno, you connect your switches to pins 8, 9, etc..., then you could just do:

```c
uint8_t combined = PINB & 0x1f;
```

Simple and fast, but not portable.

**Compatibility**: This technique is documented in the Arduino reference
on the page
[Port Registers](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation).
It applies not only to the Arduino Uno and compatible boards, but also
to all boards based on the AVR ATmega328 and ATmega168 chips, including
the Uno, Mini, Nano, Fio, Pro, as well as the older Duemilanove and
Diecimila. Boards based on the ATmega32U4 (e.g. Leonardo, Yun, Micro)
and the ATmega2560 (Mega 2560 and Mega ADK) have different pin mappings:
this technique can still be applied, but you need to select the correct
pins and the matching PINx register. The ARM-based Due has a completely
different architecture and is thus out of the scope of this technique.
The Teensy 3, although also ARM-based, supports this through AVR
emulation.

**Pros and cons**: This is roughly 200 times faster than the alternative
loop over `digitalRead()`, and is thus well suited for time-critical
work. It is also the only way to read the various inputs
*simultaneously*, and is the canonical way of reading inputs in the AVR
world. Looping over `digitalRead()`, however, is the canonical solution
in the Arduino world, as it works across the whole Arduino family, and
is based on the standard Arduino functions. The looping solution should
then be preferred for non-time-critical code that is likely to be shared
with other Arduino users who may have an incompatible board (different
pin mapping or ARM-based).

Comment: Totally not worth, imho.
What does it save? Few cycles? Some space? To which good?
It's much easier to optimize when a problem really arises than to debug/port something like that.
At minimum it should be hidden in a function/macro/method that uses it only when the right conditions are met.

Comment: yes, I do not doubt what you said, my point is solely that, unless power consumption is important, the device will basically be unused anyway.
But it's subjective opinion.
What is objective, instead, is the fact that for a generic question like this, there should be an answer that fits the various cases (think of using a DUE).
The optimized version should be confined to the problem-space it belongs to (UNO R3, for example) using some explicit means, like testing for the target #defined.
Arduino doesn't equate to AVR and even in that case, it might not be always PortB.

Comment: I'll reword the allegedly useless first comment :-D

The non portable solution should be rewritten in a way that is compatible with various scenario.

I still think that it's not easier to debug, at least not unless one has the TRM handy or knows the architecture of the uC, which is not always the case. But let's agree to disagree: we simply have different opinions on what should get higher priority.

Comment: If the question refers to "Arduino" in general, then portability _is_ a requirement. "Arduino" doesn't default to UNOR3 or equivalent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72933/discussion-between-edgar-bonet-and-igor-stoppa).